# How can I access an inner class?

Tags: java

For a school project we have been provided code in one of the classes which looks like this

```
public class Outer{
   private enum Inner{
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    EAST,
    WEST;
   }
}
```

We have not yet been taught how to use this, as it's an extension for self learning.
So I was wondering how do I get for example "NORTH" as an Inner object which I can then declare as

```
Inner i = ?
```

Thanks a lot, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: `Inner i = Inner.NORTH`

Comment: Thanks a lot, what about if Im trying to use this from another class? (ie not from the Outer)

Thanks

Comment: You can't - it's marked `private` so it is **only** accessible in `Outer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your enum is marked `private` you can only access it from within class `outer`. You do this simply by using:

```
Inner i = Inner.EAST;
```

But I think your question is about how to access this enum from outside the class. 
You have to change it's access modifier to `public` and then you can use it in other classes like this:

```
Outer.Inner i = Outer.Inner.EAST;
```

Comment: No, what makes it not an inner class is that an enum member is implicitly static.

Comment: And the access modifier needs to be `public` nonetheless.

Comment: @chrylis Isn't it then still an inner class, just a static inner class?

Comment: @1337 It's a nested class. An inner class is a non-static nested class.

Comment: @chrylis Ah, so that's the definition. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can - deliberately - expose `NORTH` to an outer object but they will not know much about `Inner` they will only know the normal details available to an `Enum` (which is actually quite a lot and includes all of the other `enum` entries).

```
public static class Outer {

    private enum Inner {

        NORTH,
        SOUTH,
        EAST,
        WEST;
    }

    public Enum exposeInner () {
        return Inner.NORTH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use private enums in basic three ways inside a class.  There are situations private enums are used inside a class.

method 1: enumName.Value.  E.g. Inner.NORTH

method 2 (special case): if you are in a switch statement and enum variable is used as the selector, then you can directly use the value without enum name. E.g. case NORTH:

method 3:
  you can use the values method to get the array consisting all the values of the enum. E.g. (for the first element): Inner.values()[0]

---

### Full code is given below:

```
public class Outer{
   private enum Inner{
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    EAST,
    WEST;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Inner i = Inner.NORTH;
       System.out.println("i = " + i + "\n");

       System.out.print("Switch Statement: \n" +
         "i = ");
       switch(i) {
       case NORTH:
           System.out.println(Inner.NORTH);
           break;
       case SOUTH:
           System.out.println(Inner.SOUTH);
       case EAST:
           System.out.println(Inner.EAST);
       case WEST:
           System.out.println(Inner.WEST);
       default:
           System.out.println(i);
       }

       System.out.println("\nUsing values method: ");
       for (Inner value : Inner.values()) 
         System.out.println("value = " + value);
       System.out.println("value of first element in the arra = " + Inner.values()[0]);
    }      

}
```